# SourceTree: how do you open the Bookmarks organiser?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I don't see a way to open the Bookmarks window in Sourcetree.

https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/05/15/bookmarks-window-reloaded/

Answer (score 1):

It's gone since the release of Sourcetree 2.0: https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2014/09/25/sourcetree-for-mac-2-0-released/

I'm pretty sure they also added this repository browser to the windows version, if that's the one you're using. On opening a new repository it should always ask you if you want to add it to the repository browser for quick access later.

Comment: Aah, yes. But if you open the repository browser up you see all the repos. How do you show the bookmarks you've made?

Comment: The repository browser is actually showing the bookmarks. You can tell because if you right-click and delete an item it will ask you if you want to remove the bookmark. The same question is asked if you open a new repository that is not yet in your repository browser.

Comment: So it is. So as to why it was showing all the repos I assume, as I had only created 2 bookmarks, it just went through my entire hard drive and created bookmarks for every repo it could find.

Comment: That feature definitely exists, but I'm pretty sure it has probably asked you if it should do that during the install or on first startup.

Answer (score 0):

This has frustrated me to no end!  It pops up sometimes when I open SourceTree, and not others.

The [SourceTree 2.0 Release Blog](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/05/15/bookmarks-window-reloaded/) Mentioned in [@Maarten00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281398/maarten00)'s post says

> If you don’t see the repository browser on load, you can show it with **Cmd-B or “Window > Show Repository Browser”** from the menu.

I upgraded to Sourcetree 4.2.5(259), on OSX 14 (Sonoma), and Now I Have

> **Window -> Show Repository Browser (⌘-O)**

If you don’t see the repository browser on load, you can show it with Cmd-B or “Window > Show Repository Browser” from the menu.

**Note:** I did not see any such menu option in 4.0.5, so apparently it's recently been revived!